# html helpers and Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

How to Name drop down list working without reload page. (Pressing using button)

Hi I want create my page more friendly for users. Now then I press use button after page reload only then data showed on the other drop-down list named name.
[image]

I know it is best way to do it with JavaScript or something like that.
Thisis code for use button

```
<fieldset>
             <legend>Select client, which you would like to use:</legend>

             @Html.Label("Client:")
             @Html.DropDownList("list", ViewData["list"] as SelectList, "-- Select Client --")
             <input type="Submit" name="button" value="Use" class="btn btn-primary" />
         </fieldset>
```

Like I understand I should grab ID from first Drop-down list, and transfer it to Name: field.

This is code for Name: field

```
<fieldset>
             <legend>Select client, which you would like to use:</legend>

             @Html.Label("Client:")
             @Html.DropDownList("list", ViewData["list"] as SelectList, "-- Select Client --")
             <input type="Submit" name="button" value="Use" class="btn btn-primary" />
         </fieldset>
```

How to make drop down list (name) working without reload page.
Because it is empty until I press USE button.(Then page reload, and only then I see data in Name field). I wanna have data in Name field then I select data from Client: (bescause Name belong from data) without pressing use button. I think it is clear now.

Comment: Still none the wiser?

Comment: I still don't understand what you're asking. What does "How to Name drop down list (name)" mean?

Comment: If i an not wrong you need `cascadding dropdown` right.

Comment: Thanks for the keyword :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, what you are asking for is a way to load one select values depending on the value selected on another one without reloading the page.

What you have to do to this is to use an AJAX call.

First you create a handler in javascript for your main select change event. 
On this handler you query your server via an AJAX call for the values of the second select related to the current value.
Finally you push those values to your select html, updating them without reloading the page.